# Put Data in DataTable, got MemoryOutOfExeption

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, out-of-memory

I have a trouble while making header from Datatable's values. I have a text file, which I search for some strings. split them and put them in Datatable. After that I use some linq codes to make column "Name" as header of this table. For small text file it works great but when i got little bigger files, my compiler throws MemoryOutOfExeption. So I'm asking how can I fix my code?

My Code:

```
        DataTable evHeader00 = resAtt.Copy();

        var prds1 = evHeader00.AsEnumerable() // make Name Values as header
                        .GroupBy(c => c["Name"])
                        .Where(g => !(g.Key is DBNull))
                        .Select(g => (string)g.Key)
                        .ToList();

        prds1.ForEach(p => evHeader00.Columns.Add(p, typeof(string))); // Here i got MemoryOutOfExeption

        foreach (var row in evHeader00.AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (!(row["Name"] is DBNull))
            {
                row[(string)row["Name"]] = row["Products"];
            }
        }
```

DataTable 1:

```
 ID    Name    Products
 1      a        A
 2      b        B
 3      c        C
...    ...      ...
```

Result:

```
ID     a   b   c   ...
1      A
2          B
3              C
...   ... ... ...  ...
```

Comment: How many rows have the  "little bigger files"

Comment: if the compiler throws the exception, it is not the data. Question is, is it really the compiler? So not while executing your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why do you need to copy the whole `DataTable` here?

   ```
   DataTable evHeader00 = resAtt.Copy();
   ```
2. Why do you create a new `List<String>` here with all your data?

   ```
   var prds1 = evHeader00.AsEnumerable() // make Name Values as header
                   .GroupBy(c => c["Name"])
                   .Where(g => !(g.Key is DBNull))
                   .Select(g => (string)g.Key)
                   .ToList();
   ```

So this should be more scalable:

```
IEnumerable<string> data = resAtt.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where(r => !r.Field<string>("Name") == null)
                                 .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Name"))
                                 .Select(g => g.Key);
```

or (as @Rawling has commented) by using `Enumerable.Distinct` which should be even more "memory-friendly":

```
IEnumerable<string> data = resAtt.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where(r => !r.Field<string>("Name") == null)
                                 .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Name"))
                                 .Distinct();
```

Now you can use a `foreach` to enumerate the result.

Comment: Would be even better to select distinct `"Name"` values rather than group by `"Name"` value and just select the keys.

Comment: Tim: so i used the code u give me `var prds1 = resAtt.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where(r => !(r.Field<string>("Name") == null))
                                 .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Name"))
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .ToList();


            prds1.ForEach(p => resAtt.Columns.Add(p, typeof(string)));`  but it throws me the same error. MemoryOutOfException

Comment: @LeVietHung: Have you seen point 2 of my answer? ;-) You don't need to create a new list, you just have to enumerate the query with a `foreach`. Note that [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.110).aspx) is not [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)!

Comment: Tim: OK, i changed my code with foreach `foreach (string st in prds1)
            {
                resAtt.Columns.Add(st);
            }` but same error, did i do something wrong here?

Comment: @LeVietHung: But you really get the exception on the `Distinct`? Have you tried to omit the `Distinct`, just to ensure that it's causing it? How many columns do you create at `resAtt.Columns.Add`?

Comment: My compiler said error in row with `foreach (string st in prds1)`, i have many linq with groupby, should i change it to distinct?

Comment: _"i have many linq with groupby"_ Then you have not shown the original code.

Comment: i add about 250 columns in resAtt, maybe the problem is with this `foreach (var row in resAtt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                if (!(row["Name"] is DBNull))
                {
                    row[(string)row["Name"]] = row["Products"];
                }
            }`because i have many "Products" Values, about 800 rows

Comment: yes, this is a fragment from my code. I'm making wins forms to convert from txt files to excel and the compiler said error with line foreach(string st in prds1), so i guess here is the problem. My original code is very long and i think none wants to read it :)

Comment: in my code i have some linqs groupby because of duplicates, should i use foreach loop to reduce duplicates instead of groupby? Do i have more memory then?

Comment: @LeVietHung: It's difficult to help without the complete code(although it might be to long). But as a rule of thumb. Avoid the `To....` methods like `ToList`,`ToArray`, `ToDictionary` if you don't need them because you just want to iterate the result.